# Configuring /etc/host file in Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, subdomain, hostname, host

I am configuring an Ubuntu server on Amazon EC2. The tutorial I am following says /etc/host to be configured like this.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.domain.com   localhost
X.X.X.X         subdomain.domain.com   subdomain
```

Suppose my site name is **abc.com**. Is the current configuration correct for my site.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.abc.com   localhost
X.X.X.X         www.abc.com         www
```

I have a doubt regarding subdomain. How exactly are they identified and written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second line should have been

X.X.X.X   www.abc.com   www

domains are hierarchical, so you can have sub1.abc.com, www.sub1.abc.com, or even www.sub2.sub1.abc.com, etc.

Comment: sorry! i intended it to be www. Is www a subdomain ?

Comment: here no, www is a host name, not a subdomain normally, but it could be, if you have www2.www.abc.com etc., but normally www is a host or a cname to mean that it serves web pages. it is entirely up to you, but a logical and intuitive system would help others, such as www.hr.abc.com, www.marketing.abc.com, etc.